# In C++, can I make cout display doubles as doubles but without touching main()?

Tags: c++

quite a specific question but I'm working on an assignment in which I have to use some operator overloads to manipulate some coordinates. The coordinates are doubles but C++ just outputs them as `(1,4)` when they're `(1.0,4.0)` as they're integers.

I've seen that I can use `std::cout.precision` to force `cout` to work to 1dp but I'm also not supposed to touch `main()` at all in my code.

Could anyone suggest another way?

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& OutStream, const Coord& Coordinate)
  {
   OutStream << "(" << Coordinate.X << "," << Coordinate.Y << ")";            
   return OutStream;
  }
```

Comment: How are you performing the operator overloading? We cannot help you if we don't see the code

Comment: Basically like this:    ```
  ostream& operator<<(ostream& OutStream, const Coord& Coordinate)
    {
     OutStream << "(" << Coordinate.X << "," << Coordinate.Y << ")";            
     return OutStream;
    }
```

Comment: sorry, can't quite get the formatting right

Comment: You don't need to put your code in comments, in the post is enough. Why don't you add `... << std::set_precision(1) << Coordinate.X << ...` in the operator definition?

Comment: Thanks! XCode doesn't seem to like that, it says 'No member named 'set_precision' in namespace 'std''. Am I maybe missing a header that includes it? I have                            #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

Comment: Sorry, it was `std::setprecision(1)` of course ..., with `include <iomanip>`

Comment: Adding on to @Damien, you can do this too: `std::cout.precision(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might add your manipulator in your operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& OutStream, const Coord& Coordinate)
{
   OutStream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1)
             << "(" << Coordinate.X << "," << Coordinate.Y << ")";            
   return OutStream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do the exact same thing in your `operator<<` definition, except changing the name from `cout` to whatever `ostream` name you've chosen:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& OutStream, const Coord& Coordinate)
{
   OutStream.precision(1);
   OutStream << "(" << Coordinate.X << "," << Coordinate.Y << ")";            
   return OutStream;
}
```